# how to sort json array by date field

Tags: arrays, json

I have a JSON list of 2-D data as

```
var data = [
    [
        'Sun Feb 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
        2,
        5
    ],
    [
        'Sun Feb 06 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
        5,
        10
    ],
    [
        'Sun Feb 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)',
         6,
         2
    ]
];
```

Where the first item of each array items is a date.

I have to sort this list by date so that **Feb 04** will come first while **Feb 06** will come last.

**How can I sort this list in JSON?**

Comment: Which language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Date object then compare the milliseconds: `new Date(date).getTime()`

```js
const data = [
  ['Sun Feb 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', 2, 5],
  ['Sun Feb 06 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', 5, 10],
  ['Sun Feb 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)', 6, 2]
];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(a[0]).getTime() - new Date(b[0]).getTime();
});

console.log(data);
```